# Display message when Timer runs out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want a message to be displayed when the countdown is completed.
I'm trying to do that with the onComplete function which I'm passing to the Timer.jsx component from App.jsx.
The function executes in the useEffect hook:

The first useEffect is setting the time that is received from the input from App.jsx.
The second useEffect is substracting the countdown value and checking if the countdown has reached 0 or not.

```
code snippet start
 useEffect(()=>{
    setCountdown(duration);
  }, [duration])
  

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (countdown === 0 && isTimerRunning) {
      console.log("reached complete")
      onComplete();
      return;
    }

    if(countdown <= 0){
      return; 
    }

    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setCountdown((prev) => prev - 1000);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [countdown, onComplete, isTimerRunning])

code snippet end
```

The problem is When I set the date from an input and click the start button,
immediately the completed message is displayed and the timer doesn't start, because "countdown <= 0 && isTimerRunning" condition is met even before the countdown is set.

Link to the project: [application_link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dmleeg?file=src%2FApp.jsx)

I want the message to be displayed after the completion of the countdown.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I saw that there was an issue with the startCountdown function

try replacing it with these functions below

```
function startCountdown(time) {
  const selectedDateTime = new Date(time);
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const timeDifference = selectedDateTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
  return timeDifference > 0 ? timeDifference : 0;
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (isTimerRunning) {
    const timerDuration = startCountdown(time);
    if (timerDuration === 0) {
      // Timer has reached 0, handle completion
      handleTimerComplete();
    } else {
      setMilliseconds(timerDuration);
    }
  }
}, [time, isTimerRunning]);
```

With this adjustment, the timer should now count down from the selected time. When it reaches 0, it will call handleTimerComplete to show the completion message.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. When the timer is set, the time duration doesn't changes. time duration is set into a state variable milliseconds and passed as a prop to the Timer.jsx component. I have provided the stackblitz link to the app also for reference.